# Quasar: Access $t inside Composition API with Single-File Components

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, quasar-framework, quasar, vue-i18n

In the [quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/options/app-internationalization#how-to-use) the following example is suggested to make translations inside a SFC script:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      content: this.$t('mykey3')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, I am wondering how to get access to `$t` from inside a script using Composition API with Single-File Components within a `<script setup>` tag.

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const example = ref($t('fldldf'))
</script>
```

The above example ends in:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $t is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `useI18n` composable function to get the `t` function:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const { t } = useI18n()

const example = ref(t('fldldf'))
</script>
```

Reference: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#usei18n

Comment: if you are using the default boot file for i18n you will also need to set `legacy: false` inside the createI18n constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
<script setup>

 ...

 import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'  

 const { t } = useI18n();

 ...

 function myFunction(myParameter) {
  
   ...

   t("i18n-key-here")

   ...

 }

</script>
```